# Air conditioning

Tags: electrical, hvac

I have a two-pole 30 amp breaker. I want to hook up to my camper but it needs 120v not 240v. Is this possible by only hooking wires to 1 leg of the breaker?

Comment: You need both hot wires to get 240.  One wire only supplies 120v.  It does not matter which half of the breaker you use.  Neutral wire must be white.

Comment: why does the title say `air conditioning` when the question is not about air conditioning? ... also why did you use the `hvac` tag?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: you want to disconnect the non-functioning house AC, and wire one side of its 30A double breaker to a suitable outside 30A outlet that you could then plug your camper into to I run _its_ AC (and other circuits). Right?

Comment: Residential air conditioning in 120/240-volt land often uses only the two hot legs (and not neutral). It's often wired with a cable that has one white and one black insulated conductor though. It sounds like this is the case with yours - can you confirm?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Please post a photo of the wires

Comment: Possibly a dumb question for you: If the AC unit doesn't work anymore, why are you trying to hook it up to your camper? A non-functioning unit won't cool the camper any better than it cools the house where it was originally installed.

Comment: Camper ac works fine

Comment: One black one white one ground took off white wire from breaker & ran wire to my camper

Answer (score 1):

#### Maybe

There is are NEMA 5-30, TT-30 and L5-30 receptacles that will accept a plug that allows for 120/125v on a 30a breaker.

If your *whatever* that you're plugging in has an appropriate plug, then you can certainly wire up one of these -30 receptacles to accept it, then connect the white wire in the panel to the neutral buss instead of the other leg of the breaker.

#### No

If you're wiring this to a 5-15 or 5-20 style receptacle to accept "standard" household appliance plugs, then no, neither the receptacle nor the device is rated for 30a and doing so would create a fire hazard.

#### Unless

Unless, of course, you pull the 2-pole 240v breaker and replace it with a pair of single-pole 15a or 20a breakers. In that case, it will be perfectly fine and legal. Of course, you'll want to replace these with GFCI (and possibly combo-AFCI, check local code) breakers for protection of wiring that's running outdoors.

Why two breakers to replace one? Because you aren't allowed to leave an open space in the breaker panel cover and this is a simple and reliable way to cover the space in the panel. I've heard it said that the replacement space covers are somewhat unreliable and aren't quite as secure as one might like. If you choose, you could use a simple, $5 (or so) non-GFCI breaker for the one not in use to save a bit of cash.